# Have multiple pages created from one controller in magento admin

Tags: php, magento

I am able to get one page to load in Magento admin using this in the controller which for this example would be in `app/code/local/me/one/IndexController.php`:

```
  public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/template')->setTemplate('one/one.phtml'));
     }
```

and I created my menu with this in the config.xml

```
 <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <catalog>
                <children>
                     <one_menu translate="title" module="foo">
                        <title>TEST</title>
                        <children>
                            <list translate="title" module="foo">
                                <title>one</title>
                                <action>one/index/index</action>
                            </list>
                            <new translate="title" module="foo">
                                <title>two</title>
                                <action>two/index/index</action>
                            </new>
                        </children>
                    </one_menu>
                </children>
            </catalog>
        </menu>

    </adminhtml>
```

But I cant figure how to create the second link in my example two/index/index ?  How would I add that second page in the controller?  What would the path be for that second link?

I tried to do something like this in the one/IndexController

```
public function twoAction ()
{ $this->loadLayout(); etc...}
```

and thought this might gnenerate a url like /one/index/two  but I dont know what I am doing (obviously).   Thanks for any help magento really confuses me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right answer and don't know it. In the XML change the second `<action>` to `one/index/two`, this will generate the correct URL. Now you can create that extra `twoAction()` method in the same controller and it will receive requests for that URL.

Read about [controller dispatches](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch) to learn more. Also try a config like [this one](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/223346/) so your URLs can start with "admin" too.

Comment: oh thanks!!  I thought I tried that and couldnt get it to load before but now it works... hmm well I am just glad it does.  Thanks for the links too :)